# How floats are stored in python

Tags: python, floating-point

I have been using python for my assignments for past few days. I noticed one strange thing that -

1. When I convert string to float - it gives exactly same number of digits that were in string.
2. When I put this number in file using struct.pack() with 4 bytes floats and read it back using struct.unpack(), it gives a number not exactly same but some longer string which I expect if as per the floating point storage

   Ex. -  String - 0.931973

   Float num - 0.931973

   from file - 0.931972980499 (after struct pack and unpack into 4 bytes)

So I am unable to understand how python actually stored my number previously when I read it from string.

**EDIT**
Writing the float (I think in python 2.7 on ubuntu its other way around, d- double and f-float)

```
buf = struct.pack("f", float(self.dataArray[i]))
fout.write(buf)
```

Query -

```
buf = struct.pack("f", dataPoint)
dataPoint = struct.unpack("f", buf)[0] 
node = root
while(node.isBPlusNodeLeaf()) == False:
    node = node.findNextNode(dataPoint)
```

findNextNode -

```
def findNextNode(self, num):
    i = 0
    for d in self.dataArray:
        if float(num) > float(d):
            i = i + 1
            continue
        else:                
            break
    ptr = self.pointerArray[i]
    #open the node before passing on the pointer to it
    out, tptr = self.isNodeAlive(ptr)
    if out == False:
        node = BPlusNode(name = ptr)
        node.readBPlusNode(ptr)
        return node
    else:            
        return BPlusNode.allNodes[tptr]
```

once I reach to leaf it reads the leaf and check if the datapoint exist there.

```
for data in node.dataArray:
        if data == dataPoint:
            return True
    return False
```

So in this case it returns unsuccessful search for datapoint - 0.931972980499 which is there although.

While following code works fine -

```
for data in node.dataArray:
        if round(float(data), 6) == dataPoint:
            return True
    return False
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening

Comment: Probably depends on python implementation as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Packing and Unpacking binary float in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165488/packing-and-unpacking-binary-float-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`float` in Python is actually what C programmers call `double`, i.e. it is 64 bits (or perhaps even wider on some platforms).  So when you store it in 4 bytes (32 bits), you lose precision.

If you use the `d` format instead of `f`, you should see the results you expect:

```
>>> struct.unpack('d', struct.pack('d', float('0.931973')))
(0.931973,)
```

Comment: But John what actually float(str) returned wasn't actually a double value.

Comment: Your problem now seems to be that you're doing direct comparison of floating-point values.  This is a cardinal sin in most languages, including Python.  For what to do about it, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python