# Pack big float value in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

There're strange thing in pack/unpack floating point data in array. It changes one of last digits of number:

```
from struct import *
data = pack("<f", 1096037602)
print unpack("<f", data)
> 1096037632
```

What factor in implementation of floating point causes it?

Comment: Well, [floating point math isn't perfectly accurate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165488/packing-and-unpacking-binary-float-in-python

Answer (score 3):

The `f` format character (almost always) implies a 32-bit IEEE floating point type. The 32-bit IEEE floating point type only uses 23 bits for the mantissa. Your number requires 31 bits.

Comment: use ```d``` format to use ```double``` (in python, ```float(8)```). check this : https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters