# How to read the voxel data from a .raw file?

Tags: image-processing

There are plenty of software that can open a raw file (I'm using ImageJ), but how about finding the data that was used to generate it?

I need to find the values stored in each voxel of the raw file.

Comment: There are lots of *"raw"* formats - raw bitmaps, raw Bayer images from CCDs, please clarify - maybe by providing a link to one. Also, please say what environment you are using - which operating system, which tool, which software - and also say what you plan to do with the voxels when you have them.

Comment: Here is the link:

http://www.sci.utah.edu/~gk/DTI-data/

I plan to store them in a file and use them in a MATLAB program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Ok, I put my learning cap on and have written it in (my style of) Python - which I have never even looked at before, so caveat emptor!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys,struct

if len(sys.argv)!=2:
    print('Usage: nrrd2txt file.raw')
    exit(1)

with open(sys.argv[1],"rb") as f:
    voxels=0
    floats=0
    while True:
        bin=f.read(4)
        if not bin: break
        floats+=1
        val=struct.unpack('>f',bin)
        if floats%7:
            print('%f ' % val,end="")
        else:
            voxels+=1
            print('%f' % val)

print('Voxels read: ',voxels)
```

**Original Answer**

There may be tools that already do this, but if you don't know of any, here is a possibility.

The header of the sample file looks like this:

```
NRRD0001
type: float
dimension: 4
sizes: 7 38 39 40
axis mins:  NaN -2 -2 -2
axis maxs:  NaN 2 2 2
data file: ./dt-helix.raw
endian: big
encoding: raw
```

So there are 7 floats for each voxel and the dimensions are 38x39x40, so a quick check yields that:

```
7 * 38 * 39 * 40 * 4 bytes per float = 1659840 bytes
```

and that matches the size of  the data file.

So, a quick and dirty Perl script to unpack that might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
################################################################################
# Unpack.pl - a quick and dirty unpacker for NRRD raw tensor data
# Mark Setchell
#
# Run with:
# ./Unpack.pl < nrrd.raw
################################################################################

open my $fh, '<:raw', 'file.raw' or die $!;

my $done=0;
while(!$done) {
   # Declare some variables
   my($binfloat,$float);
   # Read in and print 7 floats for each voxel
   for(my $i=0;$i<7 && !$done;$i++){
      if(sysread($fh,$binfloat,4)==4){
         $float=unpack('f>',$binfloat);
         printf "%f ",$float;
      } else{
         $done=1;
      }
   }
   printf "\n" if !$done;
}
close $fh;
```

And you would save it as `Unpack.pl` and run it with:

```
./Unpack.pl < nrrd.raw < file.txt
```

The output will look like:

```
1.000000 0.500000 0.000000 0.000000 0.500000 0.000000 0.500000 
1.000000 0.500000 -0.000000 0.000000 0.500000 0.000000 0.500000 
1.000000 0.500000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.500000 0.000000 0.500000 
1.000000 0.500000 -0.000000 0.000000 0.500000 0.000000 0.500000 
1.000000 0.500000 -0.000000 0.000000 0.500000 0.000000 0.500000 
...
...
1.000000 0.701893 -0.207027 0.032876 0.485446 0.071680 0.312660 
1.000000 0.765949 -0.189234 0.009855 0.426320 0.090064 0.307731 
1.000000 0.806349 -0.145439 -0.025084 0.374142 0.100883 0.319509 
1.000000 0.811200 -0.086784 -0.064337 0.341495 0.099023 0.347305 
1.000000 0.761521 -0.027021 -0.091308 0.344593 0.078665 0.393887 
1.000000 0.647051 0.010023 -0.077157 0.399438 0.040313 0.453511 
1.000000 0.534630 0.008728 -0.026470 0.472090 0.008183 0.493280 
1.000000 0.501636 0.000789 -0.001859 0.498337 0.000300 0.500027 
1.000000 0.500006 0.000005 -0.000012 0.499991 0.000001 0.500003
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had spent so much time on this! I was actually looking at the second one (Human Brain, 2000).

Are there any changes that need to be made, other than using a different NRRD file? dt-helix.raw is not referenced anywhere in the Perl script you wrote, so I guess copying the script you wrote while using a different NRRD file (the one for Human Brain) would be just fine?

Comment: It just repeatedly reads 7 floats and prints them on one line before moving to the next 7. As long as the data are in float format, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the data in Human Brain is float. Also, I'm on a Windows, so for the running part, it should work with something like Cygwin?

Comment: Yikes! I don't know `cygwin` at all. The last time I used Perl on Windows, I used Active State Perl and that was good. Do you know/have any other scripting languages or a C compiler available - that might be better than installing Perl.

Comment: I know and have Python, if that helps.

Comment: Maybe add the `python` tag to your question and see if some kind soul will translate my Perl into Python for you.... or try yourself, Python seems to have the function `pack/unpack` http://stackoverflow.com/a/16165638/2836621

Comment: I had an attempt at learning Python - it seems to work. Please have another look.

Comment: Thanks! I just made it work using Perl, so I guess I'll remove Python from the description.